# Upgraded to PS3, System.Net.WebClient not working on some machines

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-3.0

I am running in a lab environment and need to automate about 50 machines. I am trying to recover an .xml wireless network profile from a server then install it. This command is being sent from 1 server to the 50 clients.

I recently reimaged my some of my clients and upgraded from PS2 to PS3 and now my Download script is not working anymore.

It does work fine on my PS2 workstations. I am assuming that it might be a permission thing, but I'm not sure. ThrustedHosts is set to * and Script execution policy is set to Unrestricted.

Here's a snippet and the error:

```
function InstallProfile(){

clear

$fonction = 
@'
param($profileName)
$File = "c:\profiles\profile.xml"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Proxy = $NULL
$ftp = "ftp://anonymous:anonymous@192.168.2.200/profiles/$profileName"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
Write-Host (hostname)
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)
write-host (hostname) (netsh wlan add profile filename="c:\profiles\profile.xml")
'@

$profileName = Read-Host "Enter the profile name(XML file must be present in c:\share\profiles\)"

ExecCmd -fonction $fonction -argument $profileName

func_done
}
```

#

```
function ExecCmd
{
param(
$fonction, 
$argument
)

$PingTest = RetrieveStatus
$results = @{}
$results = $PingTest.up
$results | sort -uniq | out-Null

$fonctionSB = ConvertTo-ScriptBlock($fonction)

    foreach($result in $results)
    {
        $os = "Windows"
            try{
                $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $result.address -Credential $credentials -EA stop
                }
            catch{
            $os = "Not Windows"
            }
        if($os -eq "Windows"){
        Invoke-Command $result.address -ScriptBlock $fonctionSB -Arg $argument -Credential $credentials
        Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
        }
        else{
        Write-Host $result.address "does not support Powershell commands"
        }
    }

}
```

And the error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
>       + PSComputerName        : 192.168.2.110

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround,

I added a try/catch for the webclient.Download, which works for PS2. In the catch portion, I replaced the command with Invoke-WebRequest $uri -OutFile $File

Works fine for PS2 and PS3 this way!